# Meaning of nonlinear vectorial equation

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, measure-theory, nonlinear-system

I am trying to apply some methods in a paper and I have to solve the following fixed point equation from Proposition VIII.4.3 in Asmussen (2000):

$$\mu_+ =\mu \int_0^{\infty}exp((\mathbf{S}+\mathbf{s}\mu_+)y)A(dy))= \mu \hat{A}(\mathbf{S}+\mathbf{s}\mu_+) $$

We work with:
$$\mu_+ = \mu \hat{A}(\mathbf{S}+\mathbf{s}\mu_+) $$

It is given that $\mu_+ $and $\mu$ are $1 \times 2$ vectors, $\mathbf{s}$ is a $2 \times 1 $ vector, S is a $2\times2$ matrix and I have calculated that 
$$\hat{A}(z)=\frac{5.5}{5.5+4z-4.5z^2}\times \frac{p+z}{p}$$ 
where $p$ is a constant. So obviously $\mathbf{S}+\mathbf{s}\mu_+$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. Let $V=\mathbf{S}+\mathbf{s}\mu_+$

My question is how do I apply the function $\hat{A}(\cdot)$ onto $V$. Do I apply the function $\hat{A}(\cdot)$ on each element of $V$ individually to get the resultant matrix?

For e.g. if 
$$V=
\begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 2 \\
     3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then is 
$$ \hat{A}(V)=
\begin{bmatrix}
     \hat{A}(1) & \hat{A}(2) \\
     \hat{A}(3) & \hat{A}(4)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Or is this wrong and is there a correct way of applying the function here?